# Notice: Array to string conversion on PDO database connection

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm trying PDO for database connection. somehow I get this error.. or notice but I dont know why, and it doesnt output the name...

Notice: Array to string conversion in (location) on line 31, which is

```
     (print $row[0] . "\t";)
```

I dont know why?

Full code:

```
         $query = "SELECT naam FROM paginas"; 


    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute(); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $row = $stmt->fetchALL(); 

     print $row[0] . "\t";
```

Greetings,
Merijn

Comment: What is `$row[0]`? `var_dump($row[0])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PDO::fetchAll()` returns an **array of records**, where the type of a record depends on the fetch style you are using.

Since you are using the default fetch style of PDO which is [`PDO::FETCH_BOTH`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)  `PDO::fetchAll()` will return an array of arrays. In your case it will look like:

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "foo"
    'naam' =>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "bar"
    'naam' =>
    string(3) "bar"
  }

  ...
}
```

So $row[0] is an array. You will have to address an index of it. As you see in the example array I've posted above you could use:

```
print $row[0]['naam'] . "\t";
```

or

```
print $row[0][0] . "\t";
```

---

Update: If you want to loop through the records instead of fetching them all at once, then use [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php). Like this:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    print $row['naam'] . "\t";
}
```

Note that `$row` now is one dimensional array. This might be what you want.

Comment: Thanx! I'm wondering how to make it output as long as it gets input. Something like While ($row){ print $row[this value will increase]['naam'] . "\t";)